# How to set TLS Version in Java SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, security, java

I am trying to connect to a new org using the Java SOAP API and am getting the following error:

```
[UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT'
 exceptionMessage='TLS 1.0 has been disabled in this organization. Please use TLS 1.1 or higher when connecting to Salesforce using https.'
 extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'
]
]
```

Anyone know how I can set the config differently to force TLS 1.1 or 1.2? I am currently making the connection like so:

```
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setUsername(creds.username);
config.setPassword(creds.password + creds.securityToken);
config.setProxy("my.proxy.com", 80);
try {
    soapConnection = Connector.newConnection(config);
    metadataConnection = new MetadataConnection(config);
}
```

Comment: Hey, are you on a Mac or Windows machine?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, using IntelliJ and Java 1.7 if it matters.

Comment: Is it a standalone Java application or server application?

Comment: Standalone Java application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that although Java 7 and higher support TLS 1.1 and 1.2, they are not enabled by default. You can enable them by using:

```
System.setProperty(“https.protocols”, “TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2”);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the solution given in this link : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207

Pasting the excerpt for java:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also update the *java.security* file located in `JRE_HOME/lib/security/java.security:` directory.

Update `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` property and add TLSv1, TLSv1.1 to reject lower security protocol versions.

Comment: Does this answer recommend using SSLv3? Because they dropped support for that a long time ago.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the answer.